# Taguchi Method Programming Example

Tags: arrays, orthogonal

I've been asked to research some programming related to the "Taguchi Method", especially as it relates to Multi-variant testing. This is one of the first subjects I've tried to research that I've found zero, nada, zilch, code examples for, especially considering its mathematical basis.

I've found some books describing the math involved but it looks like I'm going to be doing some math brush up unless I can find some code examples I can relate to.

Is this one of those rare things that once you work out the programming, it's so valuable that no one shares? Or do I just fail at Taguchi + google?

Comment: BTW, this question should really be tagged with "Taguchi" but I can't create tags at my current SO level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taguchi designs are the same thing as covering arrays. The basic idea is that if you have F data "fields" and every one can have N different values, it is possible to construct N<sup>F</sup> different test cases. A covering array is basically a set of test cases that together cover all possible pairwise combinations of two field values, and the idea is to generate as small one as possible. E.g. if F=3 and N=3, you have 27 possible test cases, but it is enough to have nine test cases if you aim for pairwise coverage:

```
    Field A | Field B | Field C
    ---------------------------
          1         1         1
          1         2         2
          1         3         3
          2         1         2
          2         2         3
          2         3         1
          3         1         3
          3         2         1
          3         3         2
```

In this table, you can choose any two fields and any two values and you can always find a row that contains the chosen values for the chosen fields.

Generating Taguchi designs in general is a difficult combinatorial problem.

You can generate Taguchi designs by various methods:

- Branch and bound
- Stochastic search (e.g. tabu search or simulated annealing)
- Greedy search
- Specific mathematical constructions for some specific structures

Comment: Wow, amazingly fast answer, especially considering the depth of your answer! Anyway, do you have a suggestion as far as specific research area if I was trying to program testing methods for multi-variant landing page conversions?

Comment: Also, though your answer was VERY helpful and led me to many other research paths, there was a big part of the original question that went unanswered. Which was, code examples. I've still yet to find _any_ code examples which is simply amazing to me and suggests that either I'm _really_ bad at searching the web or, code examples for this are too valuable to give away.

Comment: There are some commercial companies who build the business around generating Taguchi designs, e.g. www.hexawise.com.